# Getting data from Entity Framework in one to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Entity Framework database first,
I have two tables:

- `DSRItems` (Master Table)
- `DSRItemDetails` (Slave Table)

`DSRItems` having permanent data like `ItemName`, `Category`, `Subcategory` while `DSRItemDetails` having data which changes for specific year like `completed rate`, `Number`, `Subnumber`.

1) For this when I want to show data for specific year I use following code

```
allDSRItems = db.DSRItems
                 .Where(c => c.CategoryCode == DSRCategory && c.SubCategoryCode == DSRSubCategory && c.DSRItemDetails
                 .Any(a => a.DSRYear == DSRYear) && c.DSRItemDetails
                 .Any(a => a.DSRRegionCode ==Region ))
                 .OrderBy(x => x.DSRItemDetails.Min(m => m.Number)).ToList();
```

but I am not able to show data from Slave table (`DSRItemdetails`) like `DSRYear` (May be I need some changes in razor view but I don't get exacly what to do)

2) For Edit form also I am not able to set that `DSRItemDetails` parameters as per year

I use following razor code to do that

```
  @Html.EditorFor(model =>  model.DSRItemDetails.First ().DSRYear )
```

it shows first year value I need to show user selected value from module. Do I have to change Edit controller because I am passing only one model to Edit view ie. `DSRItems`.

Answer (score 0):

May be it will help some one:

```
allDSRItems = (from items in db.DSRItems 
              join details in db.DSRItemDetails on items.CategoryID equals details.CategoryID  
              where items.CategoryCode == DSRCategory && items.SubCategoryCode == DSRSubCategory && details.DSRItemDetails=""
              select new SelectItemsList() { //Items you want to select })
```